# How can I best to get rid of/avoid dog hair on clothes

Tags: cleaning, clothing, hair, pets

Our labrador has long white hair and even though we regularly brush her and vacuum clean to get rid of as much as we can, we're constantly finding white hairs on clothes - even before ironing/hanging them up(!)

Does anyone have any good tips for how to keep our clothes looking clean when we go to wear them?

Comment: Really not possible, but on the bright side, it allows other dog people to identify you :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**What you could do:**

- Buy plastic clothes covers. Once you wash your clothes and get the hair off, this will make sure no other hair gets on.
- Use lint rollers and vacuum cleaners to remove hair on the clothing your dog has touched. A wet clothe rubbed on clothes works in a pinch. Putting your clothes through a clothes dryers can help remove some hair, as well.
- Visit a vet for your dog, if you feel the hair loss is excessive. This could be a sign of illness. Hair cuts and regular grooming can help control this.
- Don't wear things the hair will get attracted to, like wooly sweaters. Also, don't let your dog around your clothes. Getting plastic furniture covers and vacuuming carpets regularly can help with this.

Answer (score 3):

For doing this regularly you need a sticky roller. As the name suggests, this is a roller with a sticky surface and a handle, you roll it over your clothes. The more expensive ones have several layers, so you can peel one off when it's full of hairs.

Comment: They don't need to be expensive, as some cloth stores use them as give aways.

Answer (score 2):

Pet hair is a necessary consequence of owning a hairy pet and the constant presence of it is something that generally must be considered and accepted before making the decision to own a pet. Your success may be limited as long as you have a dog.

House layout permitting, buy indoor gates and don't let the dog in the laundry room or closets.

For the remaining hairs remove them with hands or other tools designed for the job, such as lint rollers mentioned in [other answer](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/a/7203/4658).

For a more unorthodox solution, as a hack you could:

- Shave your dog (removes "hair" from problem).
- Stop wearing clothes (removes "clothes" from problem).
- Dye your dog's hair a color that matches your clothes better (removes "white" from problem).
- Ask a friend to let your dog stay at their house, then never talk to them again (removes "dog" from problem).
- Avoid mirrors. Pepper spray anybody who looks at you (removes "looking [un]clean" from problem).
- Etc.

Answer (score 1):

I know of two ways to remove hair off the top of my head, both can be done easily without buying anything extra.

1. The first thing you can do is get some tape (any will do, not too weak or it won't be as effective).  What you will do is lightly tap the hair with the tape enough so it sticks to it.  Continue with it until you need another piece and/or are done.
2. The second thing I would recommend trying is wetting your hand/palm and rubbing it over the hair, this will have the hair stick to your hand.